# How to wait for second value from observable

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a situation where there is an auth guard and all routes are below it.

The **auth service** determines if the user is logged in or not by sending a request to the backend

```
private subject = new BehaviorSubject<User>(undefined)

  user$: Observable<User> = this.subject.asObservable().filter(user => !!user)

  isLoggedIn$: Observable<boolean> = this.user$.map(user => !!user.id)

constructor (private http: HttpClient) {
    http.get<User>(API['AUTH']['GET_AUTHENTICATED_USER'])
      .do(console.log)
      .subscribe(user => this.subject.next(user ? user : ANONYMOUS_USER))
  }
```

However auth guard does not seem to wait for the request to finish and gets a boolean false as the predefined value of (isLoggedIn$ observable)

**auth guard**

```
constructor (private authService: AuthService, private router: Router) {
    this.authService.isLoggedIn$.subscribe(isLoggedIn => this.isLoggedIn = isLoggedIn)
  }
```

is there a way to wait until the request completes or at least get the second value emitted through the observable?

Comment: Rather than subscribe to the observable in the guard, which makes no sense anyway, since you shouldn't be subscribing to something when you only just want to get a value once, you should instead call a method which does the check and returns true or false.

Comment: If your guard implements `CanActivate` or `CanLoad` then you should have a method `canActivate` or `canLoad` respectively that returns `Observable<boolean>`. You shouldn't need to subscribe.

Answer (score 8):

I believe the problem might come from using `Behavioursubject` here. From the docs:

> Observers can subscribe to the subject to receive the last (*or initial*) value and all subsequent notifications.

As you'll see this means that you will receive data as soon as you subscribe, if there is a default value set.

Fortunately, the docs then offer:

> If you are looking for `BehaviorSubject` without initial value see `Rx.ReplaySubject`

`ReplaySubject` doesn't send the initial value like BehaviourSubject does,  though it does still offer the benefit of being able to subscribe 'late' and still receive the latest event.

[BehaviorSubject](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/subjects/behaviorsubject.md) and [ReplaySubject](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/subjects/replaysubject.md) docs.